# Remove hidden devices

Tags: python, windows

I need to create a script in **python** to remove all hidden devices of a pc (Windows 7).

Step:

1. Check hidden devices count
2. Delete hidden devices (if > threshold)
3. Check again hidden devices
4. Send an Email

In internet I found some example with Powershell but I need to use PY.

I found also [PnPUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil), but I have to understand if it's for me.

So is it possible to create this script using python? If yes Have you got some code example? If not, why?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You could always call PowerShell from Python in case you don't find a good native solution.

Comment: I can't use Powershell.

Comment: And why is that? PowerShell is part of Windows itself since Windows 7 and therefore always available. (And if you are talking about a restricted execution environment such as found on some corporate computers, then we have a catch 22 here because as limited user you couldn't delete any devices anyway.)

Comment: My point is, [this](https://theorypc.ca/2017/06/28/remove-ghost-devices-natively-with-powershell/) already does exactly what you want. So, the easiest way would be to invoke this PS script from Python. If you don't want to involve PS, you would have to rebuild what this script is doing manually. It's using [setupapi.dll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/setupapi) which is a native Windows API DLL - you can call such APIs using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) ([example](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/ctypes.windll.setupapi/)).

Comment: I'm administrator of this PC, but for company policy I can't use Powershell commands for my scritps. So I opted to find a solution script in PY, but I have to understand if it is possible.

Comment: That's a pretty dumb policy because as administrator you can do whatever you want even without PowerShell... it's just sometimes more cumbersome. Oh well. - Anyway, you can use ctypes to interact directly with setupapi.dll as I mentioned - you can look at what the PS script does and rebuild it in Python, or the more "direct" way would be to write the whole thing in C++.

Comment: Anyway, I have another idea: There are already tools available that do exactly what you want, maybe you can use those instead of Python altogether! See https://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html#devicecleanupcmd